# Adicionar uma scroll bar num multiselect

Tags: javascript, html

Quero colocar uma scroll bar num multiselect, só que ainda não consegui descobrir como o fazer :/

Tenho o seguinte código:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Teste</label><br />
    <select id="teste" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Teste">
        @foreach (var item in listaTeste)
        {
        classHtml = "";
        if (listaIdsTestes.Contains(item.Id))
        {
        classHtml = "selected ";
        }
        <option value="@item.Id" @classHtml>@item.Abreviatura</option>
        }
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="txTeste" name="txtTeste" value="@ViewBag.TxtTeste" />
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#teste').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    nonSelectedText: 'Testes',
    selectAllText: 'Seleccionar Todos'
});
```

Deixo uma imagem de como se encontra o elemento
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que me poderá estar a faltar?

Comment: Como assim? Ele já tem scrollbar por padrão.

Comment: @Sam o que acontece é que quando abro a multiselect ele abre as centenas de opções que tenho, o que faz com que o seu tamanho (altura) seja de forma a caber todas as opções :/

Comment: Desculpe, mas não estou conseguindo entender o que vc quer fazer.

Comment: @Sam coloquei uma imagem em cima para ver se ajuda a entender o problema. Como pode ver eu não quero que, quando se abre a multiselect para se escolher os valores, que esta seja assim tão grande. O meu objetivo é colocar um scroll e diminuir o tamanho deste componente